# Four individual conditions return true, but evaluating them all at once returns false?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I think I might be losing my mind a little bit. I have a recursive function that I'm using to drill into my object hierarchies and retrieve a particular GameObject based on the following criteria:

- Object has a LayoutGroup component.
- Object has Children with a Button Component.
- Object does NOT have a Button Component itself.
- Object is active in the scene.

I've written the following recursive function to capture this:

```
private GameObject GetButtonContainerInMenuObject(GameObject menuObject, ref string buttonContainerLog)
    {
        GameObject rootObject = menuObject;
        buttonContainerLog += "\n***NEW CALLBACK***\n*MenuObject: " + menuObject.name + "; ChildCount: " + menuObject.transform.childCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < menuObject.transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            Transform menuChild = menuObject.transform.GetChild(i);
            buttonContainerLog += "\n**For Menu Child:** " + menuChild.gameObject.name + ":"
                + "\n- It has a Layout Group component?: " + (menuChild.gameObject.GetComponent<LayoutGroup>() != null)
                + "\n- It does NOT have a Button Component attached?: " + (menuChild.gameObject.GetComponent<Button>() == null)
                + "\n- It has Button component(s) in its children?: " + (menuChild.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Button>() != null)
                + "\n- It is active in the hierarchy?: " + (menuChild.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Button>() != null)
                + "\n ARE ALL OF THE ABOVE TRUE?: " + ((menuChild.gameObject.GetComponent<LayoutGroup>() != null)
                && (menuChild.gameObject.GetComponent<Button>() == null)
                && (menuChild.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Button>() != null)
                && (menuChild.gameObject.activeInHierarchy == true));

            if (menuChild.gameObject.GetComponent<LayoutGroup>() != null
                && menuChild.gameObject.GetComponent<Button>() == null
                && menuChild.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Button>() != null
                && menuChild.gameObject.activeInHierarchy == true)
            {
                buttonContainerLog += "\n***RETURNING GAMEOBJECT: ***" + GetButtonContainerInMenuObject(menuChild.gameObject, ref buttonContainerLog).name;
                return GetButtonContainerInMenuObject(menuChild.gameObject, ref buttonContainerLog);
            }
        }
        buttonContainerLog += "***NO MATCHES FOUND - RETURNING OBJECT: " + menuObject.name + "***";
        return menuObject;
    }
```

Now, this code has worked for at least one use case in my object hierarchy, but that's not what I'm here to ask about. I'm here to ask how the hell I got this log output from this method:

```
**For Menu Child:** TestCharacter_PrimaryAbility_Buttons:
- It has a Layout Group component?: True
- It does NOT have a Button Component attached?: True
- It has Button component(s) in its children?: True
- It is active in the hierarchy?: True
 ARE ALL OF THE ABOVE TRUE?: False
```

...take a look at that last line again?

```
 ARE ALL OF THE ABOVE TRUE?: False
```

Um. What? How on earth is this possible? Can someone help improve my sanity here and clarify what might be going on here? Am I just missing something really, really basic, or what?

Comment: Check this line: `It is active in the hierarchy?: " + (menuChild.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Button>() != null)`

Comment: **Pro tip:**  whenever you need to perform the same evaluation multiple times, it is best to store the result in a _variable_ so as to **1)** avoid duplication of effort **2)** reduces the chance for mistakes, the _"It is active in the hierarchy"_ being a perfect example  **3)** can be better for performance (though in the above example not considerably).

Comment: _"Um. What? How on earth is this possible?"_ -  _[The First Rule of Programming: It's Always Your Fault](https://www.computerweekly.com/blog/Risk-Management-with-Stuart-King-and-Duncan-Hart/The-First-Rule-of-Programming-Its-Always-Your-Fault)_  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DStanley pointed out, it looks like you're using the incorrect expression when you're attempting to get a boolean value for the question 'Is it active in the hierarchy?':

```
+ "\n- It has Button component(s) in its children?: " + (menuChild.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Button>() != null)
+ "\n- It is active in the hierarchy?: " + (menuChild.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Button>() != null)
```

These two are evaluating the same thing. In your final 'catch-all' evaluation, you're correctly checking for the hierarchy membership with:

```
menuChild.gameObject.activeInHierarchy == true
```

(Note - this is already a boolean value, so you can use it as-is without having to check `== true`)

In the example output, I would assume that 'activeInHierarchy' was false - that wasn't evaluated at all in the first 4 output lines.

As a suggestion, consider evaluating all of your booleans prior to writing them in the log message - you're using them again later anyway, currently you're doing the null comparison at least 3 times for each, which at the least can be confusing if you ever need to make a change.

Within your for loop, that might look something like:

```
Transform menuChild = menuObject.transform.GetChild(i);

var hasLayoutGroupComponent = menuChild.gameObject.GetComponent<LayoutGroup>() != null;
var hasNoButtonAttached = menuChild.gameObject.GetComponent<Button>() == null;
var hasButtonInChildren = menuChild.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Button>() != null;
var isActiveInHierarchy = menuChild.gameObject.activeInHierarchy;

buttonContainerLog += "\n**For Menu Child:** " + menuChild.gameObject.name + ":"
    + "\n- It has a Layout Group component?: " + hasLayoutGroupComponent
    + "\n- It does NOT have a Button Component attached?: " + hasNoButtonAttached
    + "\n- It has Button component(s) in its children?: " + hasButtonInChildren
    + "\n- It is active in the hierarchy?: " + isActiveInHierarchy
    + "\n ARE ALL OF THE ABOVE TRUE?: " + (hasLayoutGroupComponent && hasNoButtonAttached && hasButtonInChildren && isActiveInHierarchy);

if (hasLayoutGroupComponent && hasNoButtonAttached && hasButtonInChildren && isActiveInHierarchy)
{
    buttonContainerLog += "\n***RETURNING GAMEOBJECT: ***" + GetButtonContainerInMenuObject(menuChild.gameObject, ref buttonContainerLog).name;
    return GetButtonContainerInMenuObject(menuChild.gameObject, ref buttonContainerLog);
}
```

Comment: See, this is why I posted knowing full well I was missing something stupid simple like this haha - yeah, I probably should've added variables at the top for this troubleshooting, I was just throwing this log together as a part of troubleshooting and usually copy+paste stuff then delete it immediately after I find the cause in these cases, so I was trying to save myself effort when I cleared it out with having variables I only use once in the function. But I can easily see how it'd be more readable anyways with declarations, so I'll go ahead and add those. Thanks for the quick comment!